# Why would a photo's meta data show a date years earlier than when it was taken?

Tags: metadata, icc-profile

Why would the metadata show a date of 1998 if it was taken in 2018?

```
Profile Name:          Photoshop ICC profile 
Profile Cmm Type:      Lino 
Profile Version:       2.1.0 
Profile Class: Display Device Profile 
Color Space Data       RGB 
Profile Connection     Space: XYZ 
Profile Date Time:     1998:02:09 06:49:00
```

Comment: See also: [ICC version predates ICC datetime](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/100434)

Comment: It says "**Profile** Date Time". So, what is a [colour profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile)? Do you see other dates in the metadata?